# How to remove a child from a puppeteer/playwright JSelement node and then fetch innerText

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, playwright, htmlelements

I'm able to fetch the cell using playwright/puppeteer. I want to capture the following two values separately - Date and the status.

I have the following code:

```
  let allCells = await allRows[0].$$('[role="cell"]');

  let ele = await allCells[0].$('.description');
  let status = await (await ele.getProperty("innerText")).jsonValue();
       // I can get the status as 'uploaded' just fine using this

  allCells[0].removeChild(ele);    // this throws an error

  let uploadDate = await (await allCells[0]("innerText")).jsonValue();
```

The error it throws is :
TypeError: allCells[0].removeChild is not a function

console.log( allCells[0] ) returns:
JSHandle@….

Here is a relevant portion of the HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div role="cell" class="cell-body">
     <!---->Jul 11, 2021
     <div class="description">
        uploaded
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you remove a node from dom  in automation? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There can be many use cases for that. In a read only scraping, I don't care what happens to this child node, I just want the value of the parent node without whats inside this child node.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I'm taking screenshots to print physical copies, so I don't need many of the action buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot call web API methods (`.removeChild`) on JS or element handles in puppeteer (Node.js) context.

You can try to get all the data in the browser context with something like this (`.childNodes[0]` will give you just the first text node till the `<div class="description">` element):

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const html = `
  <html>
  <body>
    <div role="cell" class="cell-body">
       Jul 11, 2021
       <div class="description">
          uploaded
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>`;

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const date = document.querySelector('div.cell-body').childNodes[0].textContent.trim();
    const description = document.querySelector('div.description').innerText;
    return [date, description];
  });
  console.log(data);
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to stay with API calls and not use evaluate. But it looks like this might be the only way it works. I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: @Curious101 I think this is not the only way, but sometimes it is the simplest and fastest way: JS handles API seems very verbose and cumbersome in most cases. You can use it in this case, I think, but it will be longer and more complicated code.

Comment: Thanks. It worked, I've accepted your answer. Appreciate the effort.